# 80s Cartoon like Scooby-Doo but with an invisible dog

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This was an 80's TV cartoon series that was a lot like *Scooby-Doo*. The dog characters catchphrase was something like "it's ridiculikulous" and turned invisible (when scared?).

Comment: Can you [edit] in anymore details from [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193)? For example, any plot elements? Specific story lines?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [*Goober and the Ghost Chasers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goober_and_the_Ghost_Chasers)

It ran for one season consisting of sixteen episodes in 1973. It is very similar to *Scooby-Doo* and was created by the same production studio, Hanna-Barbera Productions. The Wikipedia plot summary mentions he can become invisible as you say (emphasis mine).

> Similar to Hanna-Barbera's successful Scooby-Doo, Where Are You!, Goober and the Ghost Chasers also features a group of teenagers solving spooky mysteries with their Afghan Hound-like dog Goober. The Ghost Chasers use their equipment from the Apparition Kit (like the Specter Detector, the Poltergeist Powder, etc.) when it comes to determining whether the ghost is real or not. The major differences were that the ghosts they eventually find are real and would help in defeating the fake ghosts. Some of those people behind the mask of some fake ghosts are not criminals. **Goober had the power to become invisible (but could not control it)** and his closest human companion is reckless instead of cowardly. Also unlike Scooby-Doo, Goober can talk more clearly, but speaks only to "break the fourth wall" with a comment aimed at the viewers; otherwise, he merely barks.

In the intro clip he also utters "it's ridiculikulous" around 25 seconds in.

This YouTube clip shows Goober becoming invisible whilst still wearing a hat at around 1 min to 1 min 10 secs.

Comment: Not shocked at all it was Hanna-Barberra. This was a pre-computer era where animation was almost prohibitively expensive in labor costs, and that particular studio was very, er, *innovative* in finding ways to do animation more cheaply. They'd be all over "its like Scooby Do, but the dog goes invisible so we don't have to animate him all the time."

Answer (score 9):

It's *Goober And The Ghost Chasers*:
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goober_and_the_Ghost_Chasers)

I remember it being shown on British TV in the mid-to-late '70s (although it may have been repeated in the '80s). The phrase "it's ridiculiculiculous" stuck in my memory ever since!

Comment: This seems to be correct (I just managed to get there before you). Can you [edit] in why you think this is correct though? At the moment it's little more than a link only comment.

Comment: Added a paragraph based on my memory of the cartoon (from 40 years ago!)